# Find string in a file and print which line it was found on

Tags: python, string, file, python-2.7, io

How can I find a string in a text file and then print which line that string was found on?

I am using Python 2.7.

Comment: What have you tried?  This can be done with `grep` by the way, so writing a new program is perhaps unnecessary in your case.

Comment: `grep` if in Unix; otherwise, I would find it hard to do =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) is handy for this sort of thing:

```
with open(myfile) as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f, 1):
        if s in line:
            print("'{0}' found on line {1}".format(s, index))
```

Comment: Yes, `s` is the target string.